# Remove duplicate files in multiple folders

Tags: linux, shell, directory-structure

I have a directory which have many sub-directories, and sub-sub-directories and so on possibly. I would like to select a particular folder say `A` and delete all the files from directory other than `A` if such files occur in both `A` and directory other than `A`. Basically I would like to remove duplication (only with reference to `A`) by keeping the files in `A` intact. Furthermore, for all files that do not occur in `A`, I would like to keep only one copy in any one of the directories (possibly based on lexicographically first directory name or any other selection criteria).

Please help me write the script for the same.

Comment: Are there only duplicates? No changed versions? No older/newer versions? So if a file exists in `A` if a file with the same name is found in `B/sub1`, the files are guaranteed to be the same? Also, does `A` have **subdirectories?**

Comment: files with same name are to be reared same regardless of their location in directories. A has subdirectories, and A and other directories from which files are to be deleted can be in same depth level.

Comment: http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/

Answer (score 3):

See **Usage:** below for examples of running this script. **Note:** this script has the actual **delete** of files **commented out**. To enable actually removing files, you will need to uncomment `# rm "$rmfn"` in the script.

**Note2:** to actually delete files, you must give this script a `3rd` argument: `-d` to cause the files to be removed. If you just provide **argument 1:** `A` (path to files to save) and **argument 2:** `pathB` (path with subdirs to look for dupes in), then **this script just prints duplicates found** so you can verify everything is as you want before preforming the removal.

**Linux application `fdupes`** I would be remiss not to tell you that there is a common application `fdupes` that is designed to do just what you are wanting to do (much more flexible and thoroughly tested).

```
#!/bin/bash

## check input dirs both exist
[ -e "$1" ] && [ -e "$2" ] || {
    printf "\nError: invalid path. Usage %s dirA pathB\n\n" "${0##*/}"
    exit 1
}

tmp="tmp_$(date +%s).txt"               # unique temp file name
[ -f "$tmp" ] && rm "$tmp"              # test if already exists and del
find "$2" -type f > "$tmp"              # fill tmp file with possible dups

for i in $(find "$1" -type f); do       # check each file in A ($1) against tmp
    fn="${i##*/}"                       # remove path from A/filename
    if grep -q "$fn" "$tmp"; then       # test if A/file found in pathB ($2)
        if [ "$3" = -d ]; then          # if 3rd arg is '-d', really delete
            for rmfn in $(grep "$fn" "$tmp"); do        # get list of matching filenames
                printf " deleting: %s\n" "$rmfn" >&2    # print record of file deleted 
                # rm "$rmfn"            # the delete command (commented)
            done
        else                            # if no '-d', just print duplicates found
            printf "\n  Duplicate(s) found for: %s\n\n" "$fn"
            grep "$fn" "$tmp"           # output duplicate files found
        fi
    fi
done

rm "$tmp"                               # delete tmp file

exit 0
```

**Usage:**

The script **requires 2 directories** as input **to scan for duplicates** and it **requires a third argument** '-d' **to actually delete duplicates found.** Example:

```
$ bash fdupes.sh ~/scr/utl ~/scr/rmtmp/

  Duplicate found for: bay.sh

/home/david/scr/rmtmp/bay.sh

  Duplicate found for: rsthemes.sh

/home/david/scr/rmtmp/rsthemes.sh

  Duplicate found for: nocomment

/home/david/scr/rmtmp/nocomment.sh

  Duplicate found for: show-rdtcli.sh

/home/david/scr/rmtmp/show-rdtcli.sh
/home/david/scr/rmtmp/subdir1/show-rdtcli.sh
<snip>
```

**Actually deleting duplicates (after uncommenting `rm`):**

```
$ bash fdupes.sh ~/scr/utl ~/scr/rmtmp/ -d

 deleting: /home/david/scr/rmtmp/bay.sh
 deleting: /home/david/scr/rmtmp/rsthemes.sh
 deleting: /home/david/scr/rmtmp/nocomment.sh
 deleting: /home/david/scr/rmtmp/show-rdtcli.sh
 deleting: /home/david/scr/rmtmp/subdir1/show-rdtcli.sh
```

Comment: FSlint app is very much faster than fdupes

Comment: But this does't compat with directories, only files. How can then?

Comment: The list of files to check for duplicates is created with `find "$2" -type f > "$tmp"` that currently excludes directories (`-type f`). If you want to include both files and directories then you can remove the `-type f` -- but know that will take additional logic to ensure there all files within the directory are duplicates before the directory is removed. `diff` would help there. To only operate on directories you can change `-type f` to `-type d` -- but the same additional logic would be required.

Answer (score 1):

In Shell script you could do something like:

```
for f in origin/* ; do rm final/*$(basename $f) ; done
```

Simple, and gets the work done.
To the second part, you could do a nested iteration, comparing all files to make sure they are unique.

```
for o in origin/* ; do
    for f in final/* ; do
        if [$(basename $f) -eq $(basename $o)] ; then
            rm $f
        else # if the file is not in A, but you want to check if its unique

            # do a new iteration
            for d in final/* ; do

                # if the file name is equal but they are not the same file, delete de second. 
                if [$(basename $f) -eq $(basename $d)] ; then
                    if [$f -ne $d] ; then
                        rm $d
                    fi
                fi                            
        fi

done
```

Comment: What about all the files in subdirectories of `A`? Say in `A/dir_a/dir_2`, etc.

Comment: Using "A/*" as a regular expression, will return all files that match the pattern, including subfolders. Take a look at: [link]http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-lpic1-v3-103-7/index.html?ca=dat

Comment: Origin could be one of the sub-directories of the final. I mean. My selected directory A could be in middle depth of the directory where I want to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Try below  code.  This will create a file with Cyrillic sum, sort  file content by cksum value,  than  iterate  on  filelist  and  remove  duplicate files.

```
find . -type f -exec cksum {}  \; > cksum.txt
cat cksum.txt |sort -n > filelist

oldSum=""
oldFile=""
while read sum lines filename
do
      echo "oldSum=$oldSum"
      echo "sum=$sum"
      echo "oldFile=$oldFile"
      echo "filename=$filename"
      if [[ "$sum" != "$oldSum" ]] ; then
        oldSum="$sum"
        oldFile=$filename
        echo 
        continue
      fi
      echo "rm -f $filename"
      rm -f $filename
      echo
done < filelist
```

Answer (score 0):

C#: 
    using System.IO;

```
string filePathA =.... //get file path in folder A
string filePathB =.... //get file path in folder B
string fileNameA = filePathA.Replace(Server.MapPath("~/ImagesA/"), "");
string fileNameB = filePathA.Replace(Server.MapPath("~/ImagesB/"), "");

if(fileNameA.ToString() == fileNameB.ToString())
    File.Delete(filePathB);
```